# Rails routing -- how to route to item with random id number

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very simple rails app. I generated scaffolding for Card which among other things allows me to go to a specific route for record with id http://app.com/cards/3.

When I go to root http://app.com I want to be routed to show a random card with random id, say "X" (http://app.com/cards/X)

I'm pretty sure this is wrong, but I attempted to add the following in the Cards Controller:

```
def random
  @card = Card.order("RANDOM()").first
end
```

And then add in routes.rb:

```
root :to => 'cards#random'
```

The error I get in browser when I try to go to route:

```
Template is missing

Missing template cards/random, application/random with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/patricia/Documents/Repos/coastguard-quiz-rails/app/views"
```

And finally when I run "rake routes" I get:

```
    cards GET    /cards(.:format)          cards#index
          POST   /cards(.:format)          cards#create
 new_card GET    /cards/new(.:format)      cards#new
edit_card GET    /cards/:id/edit(.:format) cards#edit
     card GET    /cards/:id(.:format)      cards#show
          PUT    /cards/:id(.:format)      cards#update
          DELETE /cards/:id(.:format)      cards#destroy
     root        /                         cards#random
```

Could someone please guide me in the right direction? Thanks in adv.

Comment: You're on the right track. Can you post the error you get when you go to app.com? Also, run `rake routes` and post that as well.

Comment: Hi Catfish, just added additional info. Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to redirect to the card page that you find. Currently you're receiving a template error because it's looking for the view `/views/cards/random.html.erb` but it doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
def random
  @card = Card.order("RANDOM()").first
  redirect_to card_path(@card)
end
```

Comment: Patti, I never knew you wanted to use the pre-existing "show" template.

Answer (score 1):

```
def random
   ids = Card.pluck(:id)
   ids.sample
end
```

You could select and map all existing ids to an array (that what `pluck`does), and sampling a single id from the array of existing ids. This way you make sure a card with this id is present.

Depending on your table size this might be even more efficient than loading all records into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Change the random method to this.

```rb
def random
  @card = Card.find(rand(Card.count)+1)
end
```

Your route looks fine.

As for `Template is missing` error, it's probably because you are misssing random.html.erb or random.html.haml in views/cards/ directory

Comment: garbage collection, thanks for responding. I tried this and still the same problem. I do believe there is a routing issue? When I went to rails console and entered "Card.find(rand(Card.count)+1)" it did successfully randomly generate a card ... if that info helps. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the template? I made an edit right before your comment.

Comment: I did not add a new template. At this point I'm okay with the default show template. I imagine there's several ways you could prob accomplish my end goal. Anyhoo, thanks for your help.